# ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Tags: jakarta-ee, oracle11g, weblogic

I am trying to call stored procedure with 41 parameters 9 of which are output. 33 are input parameters 4 of which are integers i.e `NUMBER(6)` and `NUMBER(12)`. rest all are `VARCHAR`.
Thus while calling the stored procedure I have set them as strings.

I get the "ORA-01461: can bind a `LONG` value only for insert into a `LONG` column" error and I am unable to insert the data. Did a lookaround on Google and set `oracle.jdbc.RetainV9LongBindBehavior = true` in the data source property. But no luck. I do not know what can be the issue as I am not using any Long datatype. Nor am I inserting a string which is too big for the Varchar to handle.

Comment: Really hard to guess what your problem is without seeing the procedure/tables and your calling statement. Everything points to inserting a value that is too large for your varchar...

Comment: I can successfully insert the data if I exclusively call the stored procedure in Oracle. But if I hard code the same data using my application it gives me this error.

Comment: are you using ibatis as orm?